# jQuery chosen sets wrong value on second time

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have implemented the jQuery Chosen plugin on this `select`:

```
<select class="form-control chosen-select" id="officeLocation" data-ng-options="state.name as state.name for state in stateList" data-ng-model="inviteObj.state"></select>
```

The first time a selection is made, it shows the correct value. The second time a value is chosen, it shows the correct value in HTML, but when I print `data-ng-model` value it shows the auto incremented value of `data-ng-model`.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed example? I don't understand what do you want to get and what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.

That's probably because the value of your model **inviteObj.state** match none of the options from **stateList**.

In this case AngularJS automatically creates an option valued **?** or something. But as soon as you select a value, the automatically created option is gone. That creates the shift the second time you select a value.

I solved the problem by adding a blank value to the list and initializing the model to a blank value. Something like this:

```
myModel.OptionsList.push('');
myModel.SelectedOption = '';
```